# Unity- how to do JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have got an issue like

> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or `List<T>`) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

My json file

```
{age : 20}
```

userinfo.cs

```
[System.Serializable]
public class UserInfo
{

public string age ;

[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConstructor]
public UserInfo(string _age )
{
    age = _age ;


}}
```

main.cs

```
 public List<UserInfo>userInfoListw 
  userInfoListw = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserInfo>>(Resources.Load<TextAsset>("User").ToString());
```

I know one of solution could be `[{age : 20}]`, 
but I do not really want to put `[]` into my Json file,
Please let me know another way to solve it.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking but your json in this question is really simple to de-serialize without any external lib: `UserInfo userInfo= JsonUtility.FromJson<UserInfo>(jsonString);`

Comment: You code will not compile because `List<UserInfo>` and `List<Datum>` are not the same types. You should do `var userInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(Resources.Load<TextAsset>("User").ToString());` and `userInfoListView.Add(userInfo);`

Comment: Chetan Ranpariya/ Thanks it works :)!

Answer (score 0):

> I know one of solution could be [ {age : 20}], but I do not really want to put [] into my Json file, Please let me know anther way to solve it

Well, you're deserializing the JSON data into a List object. But your JSON data is not actually a List.

> `{age : 20}`

If you deserialize it as a List, then Newtonsoft's library is going to expect a collection in the JSON (array brackets, like you pointed out). So either it's a List, or it isn't. You can either make it a collection with a single element -- which requires you to wrap the JSON in brackets, which you stated you don't want to do -- or you can change your code so it does not deserialize it into a List:

`public UserInfo userInfow 
  userInfow = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(Resources.Load<TextAsset>("User").ToString());`